# How to add framework project into main project and configure settings of framework project from main project

Tags: ios, frameworks, compiler-flags

I am working on a framework project where I have some build configuration(configure flags) defined in project settings. Now I want to add this framework project to main project and configure those compiler flags from main project.

Thank you :)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? I know of two ways to add a framework to a project - one will allow you to edit the framework source and rebuild all targets at the same time, and the other won't. Could you add a bit more detail to what you want?

Comment: @dfd thank you for your reply. I want to add the whole framework project not to build target each time. my target is to allow the main project to configure some flags in framework project

Comment: Then I believe @batu gave you the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

You should drag&drop your framework under your project. Then add that framework to your app target's "Link Binary With Libraries" phase. Then you should add a "Copy Files Phase" to your target's build phase:

[image]

Don't forget to set "Destination" to "Frameworks". If you don't add this phase and and your add framework here, your app will crash with "image not found" error when it tries to load your framework.

Your app's build phases tab should look like this:

[image]

If you get build time error like "file not found" or "framework not found", you might need to add your frameworks path to Your app target -> Build Settings -> Header Search Paths and Your app target -> Build Settings -> Framework Search Paths

Comment: thank you for the answer, yes i was able to do that in my case. but how can i configure the framework project's build configuration such as flag value from main project's build settings.

Comment: Then you should include your framework's project in your application's project as dependency and set your framework's build settings there. Your framework will be generated every time you build you app (which is not what you wanted, but it's the only way).